# Convert mongodb return object to dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, bottle, mongoengine

I'm using the bottle framework together with mongoengine.
I have an orders model :

```
class OrderDetail(Option):
    orderDetailsQty = FloatField()

    def to_dict(self):
        return mongo_to_dict_helper(self)


class Order(Document):
    userName = StringField(required=True)
    orderDate = DateTimeField()
    orderStatus = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Status))
    orderDetails = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(OrderDetail))
    orderComments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    isActive = BooleanField()

    def to_dict(self):
        orderObj = mongo_to_dict_helper(self)
        orderDetailList = []
        for orderDetail in orderObj["orderDetails"]:
            orderDetailList.append(orderDetail.__dict__)
        orderObj["OrderDetails"] = orderDetailList
        return (self)
```

When mongodb is queried I get an object which is then converted in to a dict by using the following function :

```
def mongo_to_dict_helper(obj):
    return_data = []
    for field_name in obj._fields:
        if field_name in ("id",):
            continue
        data = obj._data[field_name]

        if isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], StringField):
            return_data.append((field_name, str(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], FloatField):
            return_data.append((field_name, float(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], IntField):
            return_data.append((field_name, int(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], ListField):
            return_data.append((field_name, int(data)))
        else:
            # You can define your logic for returning elements
            pass
    return dict(return_data)
```

I found this function after a long search in the internet. Later found out that this function also fails while defining a member as the ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(obj)).

I also tried writing a condition for catching the specific case of EmbeddedDocumentField :

```
elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], EmbeddedDocumentField):
    return_data.append(mongo_to_dict_helper(data))
```

but that didn't do any good either.

Anyone have a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: You are trying to convert whole queryset to a dict or just one document?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to convert one object to json
I was unaware of the to_mongo() function...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What about just using `to_mongo` method of an object to convert it to a dict?

```
object.to_mongo()
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. But still I get an error TypeError that the ObjectId is not serializable.

Comment: Pasting a link to to_mongo() documentation will be greatly appreaceated as I cant find one anywhere. Thanks @alexvassel

Comment: Actually, i did not find this method in the official documentation) So it is only looking into a source)

Comment: And about your error, try to serialize the str(ObjectId). Actually, i don't know what are you trying to do, so it is just a guess.

Comment: Is possible dereference all reference fields recursively using to_mongo()?

Comment: @alexvassel how to use this method?? from this `inbox = Inbox.objects.filter(messages__to_users__in=[username]).to_mongo()` i got this `'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'to_mongo'`

Comment: @holms you can use a comprehension: `[ob.to_mongo() for ob in query_set]`

Comment: Is there a `from_mongo()` as well? Does the `to_mongo` store metainfo to restore the object?

Comment: ```object.to_mongo()``` returns [SON object](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html) to get a dictionary you need to call ```to_dict()``` method: ```object.to_mongo().to_dict()```

Answer (score 37):

Expanding on @alexvassel's and @z0r's answers, calling `.to_mongo()` converts the object to a [SON instance](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html). Once you have it, you can call its [`.to_dict()` method to convert it to a dictionary](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html#bson.son.SON.to_dict).

For example... (`qset` is a queryset that's returned from mongoengine, after e.g. `Posts.objects.all()`).

```
sons = [ob.to_mongo() for ob in qset]
for son in sons:
    print str(son.to_dict())
```

Comment: `to_mongo` accepts `use_db_field` argument, which should be False if you have a field with a custom `db_field`.

Answer (score 13):

```
import json
json.loads(yourobj.to_json())
```

Comment: This is my most favorite answer in this thread, however, it returns a `list` of `dicts` and not a `dict` directly - even though there is just one result. In order to access one `dict` you have to access the `lists` objects like `list[i]`. Otherwise this is a great solution!

Answer (score 12):

Extending on @alexvassel's answer, `to_mongo()` method  returns [SON object](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html), which you can convert to dict by calling its `to_dict()` method

```
object.to_mongo().to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can custom method to convert object to dict

```
class Order(Document):
    userName = StringField(required=True)
    orderDate = DateTimeField()
    orderStatus = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Status))
    orderDetails = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(OrderDetail))
    orderComments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    isActive = BooleanField()

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "user_name": self.userName,
            "order_date": self.orderDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        }
```

now you can use obj.as_dict() to dict

```
orders = Order.objects.all()
datas = [each.as_dict() for each in orders]
```

Comment: so how about `orderStatus`,`orderDetails` and `orderComments` which is a `EmbeddedDocumentField` ,and in some case is a `ReferenceField`,in such case,how can it be done??

Comment: @ken,you can define as_dict() at ReferenceField, and` "order_status":self.orderStatus.as_dict()`; or, you can use aggregate,`obj.objects.aggregate([{"$lookup":{"localField":"orderStatusId","foreignFiled":"_id","form":"orderStatus","as":"order_status"}}])`

Answer (score 0):

combining all other answers,

```
import json
dict = {'data':[json.loads(ob.to_json()) for ob in qset]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenario.

1. when query returns CommandCursor object

```
    **records = list(CursorObject)**

    ex - Class.objects().aggregate({...})
```

2. when query returns BaseQuerySet object

```
   **import json**

   **records = json.loads(BaseQuerySetObject.to_json())**

   ex - Class.objects().filter(..)
```